# Fragment Animation makes call google map "onCameraChange" constantly

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, coding-style, solid-principles

My activity has this elements:

- A big Google Map that covers all the screen.
- A Fragment at the bottom that appears after an animation and certain events happen (wifi, gps position...)

I have defined a onCameraChange method to get some data from a DB.

```
map.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
        SpotsMapActivity.cameraPosition = cameraPosition;

        mClusterManager.onCameraChange(cameraPosition);
        presenter.onMapViewUpdate(map.getCameraPosition().target, cameraPosition.zoom);
    }
});
```

The problem is that the fragment animation make constantly call onCameraChange method. CameraPosition has not changed its values, always has the same lat/lon and zoom.

How can i avoid this constant re-calling?

EDIT:

This is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.github.rahatarmanahmed.cpv.CircularProgressView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/map_progress_view"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:cpv_animAutostart="true"
        app:cpv_indeterminate="true"
        app:cpv_thickness="8px" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/map_toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/map_status_banner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"/>

   <!-- <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_big_card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/card_big_height"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" /> -->

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/map_my_location_custom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/map_status_banner"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_my_location"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/white"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:fromYDelta="1000"
        android:duration="1500"/>

</set>
```

Comment: Can you post the code about your fragment animation? Not sure why it will call the `setOnCameraChangeListener()`. Also, you can use a temp variable to check if the position is the same, if same, just return before doing other stuff in that listener method.

Comment: Thank you, I have added the main layout and the animation.

Comment: I think changing this presenter.onMapViewUpdate(map.getCameraPosition().target, cameraPosition.zoom); to presenter.onMapViewUpdate(cameraPosition.target, cameraPosition.zoom);  may work